# EF Code First Migrations stopped applying suddenly

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, entity-framework-migrations

I have an asp.net core 2.2 web application. I opened it in Visual Studio 2019 and published to the same app service I had been publishing to for months. Just now, I noticed that my latest EF migration did not apply. I researched it and found that there is some kind of VS 2019 bug with this. I opened the solution in VS 2017 and tried publishing and it still won't apply the migration. How do I troubleshoot this? ANyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to get around this problem?

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    //Bunch of other DbSet's here...

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
```

Comment: not enough information, show code how you apply migrations. If you can reproduce the problem locally then step through the code and see if there is an error when it tries to apply the migration.

Comment: The migration applies locally. The migration does not apply when I publish to the app service despite the fact that I provide the connection string to the Azure SQL Database.

Comment: you still should show the code in your application that is supposed to apply the migrations so we can see what you are doing. please add code to your question.

Comment: I added the initial and 15 subsequent migrations using the Add-Migration command with the Package Manager console. I ran the Update-Database command for each one. This updated my local development database. Each time I published to the App Service in Azure, my migrations were automatically applied to the Azure SQL Database. Then for unknown reasons, on the 16th migration, publishing no longer applies the migration to the Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I normally add code in the program.cs to apply migrations. This is better than using Update-Database because it will apply migrations automatically both in dev and in production when you deploy. Without that I don't see how migrations would get applied automatically in Azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

EF Code-First will look at your DbContext, and discover all the entity collections declared in it (and also look at entities related to those entities via navigation properties). It will then look at the database you gave it a connection string to, and make sure all of the tables there match the structure of your entities in model. If they do not match, then it cannot read/write to those tables.

**Option 1**

You could use Database Initialization Strategies in Code-First (**`DropCreateDatabaseAlways`**) to update your test environment database. For more information, please refer to:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

**Option 2**

You could update your test environment, and then add a blank migration. For more information, please refer to:

http://devgush.com/2016/02/05/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-in-a-team-environment/